# restriction of affine schemes morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

Seems like its somehow obvious that if (X,O) and (Y,F) are affine schemes, (f,f^#) is a morphism of schemes between them (from X to Y) and U in X is an open affine, so the restriction morphism of (f,f^#) from U (with the induced sheaf structure, of course) to Y is just the composition of (*res*)* with f, where *res* is what we call the restriction map (from the sheaf structure) from O(X) to O(U) (and (*res*)* is the induced map on the spectrums).

I cant really understand why is it true, especially if X is not equal to the spectrum of some ring, and just isomorphic and why it seems so obvious.

Comment: You appear to be thinking you have two maps and want to show an equality between the two. It seems to me you do not; you have a definition and a name for that definition. I don't think there is anything to show here.

Comment: we have the "simple" defenition of restriction map - and that is what Im talking about with f. A map from U to Y that acts on U exacly how f does. We have restriction maps from the sheaf - which dont have to actually restrict something like we defined earlier, especially if you take in mind that the elements in the rings dont have to be functions. We also have the (*res*)* - which its domain is the spectrum of O(U). When X is directly Spec(A) it may be easier to talk about the canonically identification of Spec(O(U)) with U, so one can work over the Spec and its the same as working in U.